# Flex Viewer access to layout widgets

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

How can I get layout widgets objects dynamically? In case of typical widgets it can be achieved by

```
  FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.widgetManager.getWidget()
```

, however i can't find a way to get to the layout widgets like navigation or map switcher.